# Basler camera and DIPlib

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, diplib

How can I convert a Pylon image (from the Basler camera library) to a DIPlib image in the C++ language?

The code below illustrates how to convert the Pylon image to an OpenCV image:

```
// Convert the grabbed buffer to a pylon image.
formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);

// Create an OpenCV image from a pylon image.
openCvImage = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t *)pylonImage.GetBuffer());
cvtColor(openCvImage, openCvImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: Are you referring to this DIPlib: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched online for documentation to the Pylon API, but couldn't find it. Nonetheless, using the example for OpenCV you gave, it is easy to do the equivalent in DIPlib:

```cpp
dip::Image image(
   NonOwnedRefToDataSegment(pylonImage.GetBuffer()), // a random, non-owning pointer
   pylonImage.GetBuffer(),          // data
   dip::DT_UINT8,                   // pixel type (8-bit unsigned)
   { ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(),
     ptrGrabResult->GetHeight() },  // width and heigh
   {},                              // this one can stay empty
   dip::Tensor{3}                   // 3 channels
);
image.SetColorSpace("RGB");
```

See the documentation to [this constructor](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/dip-Image.html#dip-Image-Image-dip-DataSegment-CL-void-P-dip-DataType--dip-UnsignedArray--dip-IntegerArray--dip-Tensor-CL-dip-sint--dip-ExternalInterface-P) as well as [this section of the DIPlib documentation](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/dip-Image.html#use_external_data) for more details.

Alternatively, you can use [this simplified alternative to the constructor above](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/dip-Image.html#dip-Image-Image-T-T-CP-dip-UnsignedArray--dip-uint-), making the code a lot simpler. This constructor requires "normal" data ordering, which you do have in this case:

```cpp
dip::Image image(
   static_cast<uint8_t*>(pylonImage.GetBuffer()) // data pointer
   { ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(),
     ptrGrabResult->GetHeight() },               // width and heigh
   3                                             // 3 channels
);
image.SetColorSpace("RGB");
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2664 'dip::Image::Image(const dip::DataSegment &,void *,dip::DataType,dip::UnsignedArray,dip::IntegerArray,const dip::Tensor &,dip::sint,dip::ExternalInterface *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'uint8_t *' to 'dip::UnsignedArray' servoqei c:\users\tcc\source\repos\servoqei\servoqei\pylonframe.cpp 93   I am receiving above error message

Comment: @AhmetManyasli: Could you please submit an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/issues), including more of the code and the full error message? It'll be easier to communicate that way than through comments here. Thanks!